# Weak convergence in reflexive space is equivalent to singleton intersection of the convex hulls

Tags: banach-spaces, reflexive-space

#### Question

> Let $X$ be a Reflexive space. Suppose $(x_n)_n \in X$ is a bounded sequence and define $K_n=\overline{conv\{x_m,m\geq n\}}$. Then $x_n\overset{w}{\to}x_0$ if and only if $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}K_n=\{x_0\}$.

So I know that $K_n=\overline{conv\{x_m,m\geq n\}}=\overline{conv\{x_m,m\geq n\}}^w$ by Mazur's Theorem and thus $x_0\in K_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Meanwhile the $K_n$'s form a decreasing sequence so if I could show that $diam K_n \to 0$ I could just use Cantor's Theorem. I don't suspect something like this actually happens however and I am not sure how to use the reflexive property.

Comment: "for the only if part I think we can ... show norm convergence". huh? are u saying weak convergence implies norm convergence?

Comment: No I meant the intersection could imply norm convergence but I think it's not the case

Comment: if norm convergence were implied, then what you would be showing was that weak convergence implied norm convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \overset{w}\to x$. Take $y \in \cap_{n \ge 1} K_n$. Fix $l \in X^*$. Take $\epsilon > 0$. Take $N \ge 1$ so that $|l(x_n)-l(x_0)| \le \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Note $y\in K_N$ implies that there exist $k \ge 1$, $N_1,\dots,N_k \ge N$, and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i=1$ and $\|\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ix_{N_i}-y\|<\frac{\epsilon}{||l||}$. Then $$\left|\ell(y)-\ell(x_0)\right|\leq \left|\ell(y)-\ell(\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ix_{N_i})\right|+\left|\ell(\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ix_{N_i})-\ell(x_0)\right|$$ $$\leq\epsilon+\left|\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\ell(x_{N_i})-\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\ell(x_0)\right|$$ $$\leq\epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\left|\ell(x_{N_i})-\ell(x_0)\right|\leq 2\epsilon,$$ the last holding since each $N_i\geq N$. As this inequality holds for any $\epsilon>0$, we have that $\ell(y)=\ell(x_0)$ for all $\ell\in X^*$. And since $X^*$ separates points, we see $y=x_0$.

For the "if" direction, suppose $x_n \not\overset{w}\to x$. Since $(x_n)_n$ is bounded and $X$ is reflexive, there is some $y \not = x$ so that $x_{n_k} \overset{w} \to y$ for some subsequence of $(x_n)_n$. But, once again, as you've already shown, $y \in \cap_{n \ge 1} K_n$.

Comment: Ok the "if" direction I totally get, what do you mean by $\langle x,y \rangle$ I know this in functional analysis as applying the linear functional $x\in X^*$ on $y$, is it some sort of inner product?

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης whoops, fixed.

Comment: Amazing I will award the bounty asap, one minor thing though I do not like the limit notation there so I will suggest an edit that makes it a bit clearer and more $\epsilon-\delta$ style

Comment: In case you are wondering the $x_{n_i}$s and their number changes and this messes things up a bit imo as you cannot actually write $1$ a linear combination of $\lambda_i$ that are uniquely defined, I mean it is possible that $\lim_{j\to\infty}{\lambda_i}^{(j)}$ doesn't make much sense

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης i approved your edit, but I actually think it made sense before. We can call those vectors $v_j$. We knew $v_j \to y$, so $l(y) = \lim_{j \to \infty} l(v_j)$. I never suggested to put the limit inside the sum that $v_j$ is made out of. I was just saying that since $|l(v_j)-l(x_0)| \le \epsilon$, we know $|\lim_{j \to \infty} l(v_j)-l(x_0)| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: I see, yes I am not suggesting it is wrong, this is why I approved the answer in the first place! I simply suggested this edit because I understand it better and I feel it does better justice to your proof. I do get what you mean now so yes it is perfectly reasonable

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης awesome. i edited the answer a bit more, since there was some imprecise language about the quantifier on $\delta$, and because you can just take $\delta = \epsilon/||l||$.